# What does this regex do (/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm debugging someone's code and wondering what this regex does?

Code:

```
<script>

 var t = document.getElementById("filterVal").value;
 var s = filterVal.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1')

</script>
```

Comment: It would take a string like this `"dummy string"` and make it this: `dummy string`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It removes a balanced count of double quotes.

```js
console.log('a"bc"de"f'.replace(/"([^"]+)(?=")"/g, '$1'));
console.log('a"bc"d"e"f'.replace(/"([^"]+)(?=")"/g, '$1'));

// a version without a positive lookahead (looks like the same result)
console.log('a"bc"de"f'.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, '$1'));
console.log('a"bc"d"e"f'.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, '$1'));
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time for providing the examples.

Answer (score 1):

As stated basically removes the qoutes: say filteVal = "It's sunny today"

```
 var t = document.getElementById("filterVal").value;
 var s = filterVal.replace(/"([^"]+(?="))"/g, '$1')
//output: It's sunny today
```

You can also try it out by just right clicking in chrome and opening inspect and    typing it out in the console.